# Includepdf puts headings into the pdf document and not above

Tags: pdfpages

I have a pdf-document which has 2 pages. I would like to put this document into my tex-file. Above the document the heading should be **Anlage B**.

What I did is the following:

```
\includepdf[pages=1,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{empty}\textbf{Anlage B}}]{name.pdf}

\includepdf[pages=2-]{name.pdf}
```

The problem is that **Anlage B** is written *in* the document, not *above*. What can I do to get the heading above the document?

Comment: try with `\thispagestyle{myheadings}\markboth{\textbf{Anlage B}}{\textbf{Anlage B}}}`

Comment: its still in the pdf-file, not above

Comment: well, 2 solution : 1) add the scale option `[page=1,scale=.95,...` and try to find the good value 2) change localy the page layout using `\newgeometry{....}` before `\includepdf` and restoregeometry after.

Comment: @touhami Thanks, using the scale option works fine. The pdf-document is still big enough and the heading now is above the document, great.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.